# Como mudar a imagem quando passar o mouse em cima

Tags: javascript, html

Estou fazendo uma area de serviços do meu site(wordpress), e gostaria de adicionar apenas imagens nele e quando o usuário passar o mouse em cima dessas imagens essa imagem mudar para uma outra assim com o nome do serviço que era aquela primeira...

Gostaria de saber oq é necessário para fazer isso... se da para fazer pelo HTML, ou se vai ser por css ou javascript...

Desde já obrigado.

Por enquanto assim está o codigo.

```html
<div class="servicos">
  <div class="container">
   <div class="row">

    <div class="col-md-3 col-lg-3">
     <img class = "img-responsive " src = " <?php bloginfo('template_directory' ); ?> /assets/images/logobeta.png">
    </div>
     <div class="col-md-3 col-lg-3">
     <img class = "img-responsive " src = " <?php bloginfo('template_directory' ); ?> /assets/images/logobeta.png">
    </div>
     <div class="col-md-3 col-lg-3">
     <img class = "img-responsive " src = " <?php bloginfo('template_directory' ); ?> /assets/images/logobeta.png">
    </div>
     <div class="col-md-3 col-lg-3">
     <img class = "img-responsive " src = " <?php bloginfo('template_directory' ); ?> /assets/images/logobeta.png">
    </div>



   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Para alterar o *source* de uma imagem para uma nova fonte é necessário utilizar Javascript:

```js
var x = document.querySelectorAll('.servicos .col-md-3');
var novaImg = 'https://lorempixel.com/400/100/sports/5';

for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    novoX = x[i];
    novoX.addEventListener('mouseover', function(event){
        this.querySelector('img').src = novaImg;
    });
}
```

```html
<div class="servicos">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <img src="https://lorempixel.com/400/100/sports/1"/>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-3">
                <img src="https://lorempixel.com/400/100/sports/2"/>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-3">
                <img src="https://lorempixel.com/400/100/sports/3"/>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

No entanto se quiseres mostrar uma outra imagem apenas enquanto o *mouse* estiver a fazer *hover* em uma imagem, podes fazer algo como no exemplo abaixo apenas com CSS:

```css
.col-md-3 {
    position: relative;
}
.col-md-3 .seg {
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
}
.col-md-3:hover .seg {
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-md-3">
    <img class="pri" src="https://lorempixel.com/400/100/sports/1"/>
    <img class="seg" src="https://lorempixel.com/400/100/sports/5"/>
</div>
```

Ou usando a imagem como background:

```css
.col-md-3 {
    width: 400px;
    height:100px;
    background-image: url(https://lorempixel.com/400/100/sports/1);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
.col-md-3:hover {
    background-image: url(https://lorempixel.com/400/100/sports/5);
}
```

```html
<div class="col-md-3"></div>
```